# "Error: cs0016 could not write to output file ... access is denied"

Tags: iis

How can I fix the following error?

> error: cs0016 could not write to output file...c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\sitename\6c57f9d2\bb09b49d\App_global.asax.5odzsyz5.dll'  access is denied

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was struggling with this problem for a while.
Found some solutions on the web that involved setting permissions on the "Temporary ASP.NET Files" directory in the error message.  But even opening it up to "Everyone" didn't work.

Then eventually the following steps fixed it:

1. Go to the IIS AppPool for this site
2. Right-click the app pool and go to Advanced Settings
3. Change Identity from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "NetworkService"

There may also be some other necessary steps, which I did while troubleshooting, but this is the key step.  For some reason the App Pool Identity (such as IIS_APPPOOL\SiteName) isn't granted access when "Everyone" is.  I'm sure someone else can shed some light on why this is the case...  Hopefully this helps others resolve this frustrating issue.

Comment: is it normal that when you do this, your applications counts turned to zero but when you check your applications it's all there?

Comment: I change it to LocalSystem and it worked. and i give premission to IUSR too.

Comment: This is not a solution but a work around. Besides, it is also going against IIS best practices, as if you have multiple application pools running on the same user, their memory and accesses are not isolated from each other. In other words, firstly, it is best to keep your applications isolated from each other by using different application pool identities; secondly, it is better to give least possible accesses, and giving `Local System` to the application that doesn't need it is a 'carte blanche'.

Answer (score 33):

After spending hours on this issue myself below is the solution that worked for me on Windows 7 running IIS 7.5:

The application pool identity associated with the site was not a member of the IIS_IUSRS group. To add the app pool identity to the group I used the following steps:

1. From the start menu select Run… enter lusrmgr.msc and click OK.
2. Select Groups.
3. Double click the IIS_IUSRS group.
4. Click the Add... button.
5. Click the Locations... button.
6. Select your computer name (it should be at the top of the list) and click OK.
7. In the text box below "Enter the object names to select" enter:
   iis apppool\<app pool identity> e.g. iis apppool\dev
8. Click the Check Names button. If a Name Not Found dialog box appears then verify that the app pool identity entered matches the app pool identity associated with the site. If a dialog box did not appear then click OK.

Repeat steps 7 through 8 for each app pool identity you wish to add.
Click OK.

Now the app pool identity is a member of the IIS_IUSRS group which should already have access to the Temporary ASP.NET Files directory. After all that I was still receiving the error and I found (thanks to [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)) it was because the app pool identity could not write to the windows temp directory. To resolve this I added the IIS_IUSRS group to the windows temp directory with read/write permissions.

1. From the start menu select Run… enter %windir% and click OK.
2. Right click on the Temp directory and select Properties.
3. Click on the Security tab.
4. Click the Edit... button.
5. Click the Add.. button.
6. Click the Locations... button.
7. Select your computer name (it should be at the top of the list) and click OK.
8. In the text box below "Enter the object names to select" enter: iis_iusrs
9. Click the Check Names button. If a Name Not Found dialog box appears then check for typos. If a dialog box did not appear then click OK.
10. Select the added IIS_IUSRS group and in the Permissions for Everyone box below select:
    Allow Read and Allow Write
11. Click OK. A dialog box will be displayed stating that "You are about to change the
    permission settings on system folders, which can result in unexpected access problems
    and reduce security. Do you want to continue?"
12. Click Yes
13. Click OK

Comment: These were very good directions. In addition though I had to use System Internal's Process Monitor utility and filter for Access Denied Results for the w3wp.exe and csc.exe process when attempting to load the site, then grant modify access to the folder paths denied access for the IIS_IUSRS group.

Comment: Saved my day! Only one thing extra I did to make it work for me, I allow the IIS_IUSRS the permission of "modify"

Comment: This solved the issue for me on an IIS 8.5 on Server 2012 R2. THANK YOU for this very awesome guide, I would have never figured this out on my own!

Comment: Can someone explain why my Application Pool wants to write into `C:\Windows\Temp`? Also, just an observation, I have multiple application pools on one IIS instance, all of them are using ApplicationPoolIdentity, however only some pools give this strange error but not all of them. Why?

Answer (score 18):

I've fixed this issue setting full control for 'NETWORK SERVICE' to the system temp:

**C:\Windows\temp**

The error message reported by the web server is a bit misleading.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Might work, but many will get a Error Applying Security Error

Comment: I've tried loads of things. But finally this solution works for me. Thanks @Jako.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem.
Found an easy way to resolve: Set "Load user profile" to true in app pool's advanced settings.

Comment: This helped where all the other solutions didn't - Thank a lot!

Answer (score 4):

For **Windows 7** Set `Full Control` Permissions on folder `C:\Windows\Temp` for user `IIS_IUSRS`

`Network Service` user usually only applies on servers

Comment: This worked, when everything else failed. The error message in the event log was even complaining about the `Temporary ASP.Net Files` directory, yet `C:\Windows\Temp` was the culprit. Added IIS_IUsers, Full Control, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I found the accepted answer on this post to be correct in process. I tried "NetworkService" and it did not work. However "LocalSystem" did!

Comment: Welcome to the site! [Please use Answers exclusively to answer the question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/92107). To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). In the meantime, please do not use answers to post comments.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Go 
C:\Windows\Temp
Right Click on Temp Folder > go To Security Click on Edit 
Add New User [IIS_IUSRS] AND GIVE IT FULL PERMISSION. Then Press Ok,

Answer (score 1):

Just just need to set permissions for "Temp" folder.

1. Go to "C:\Windows\Temp"
2. Right click on it, and go to security.
3. Set permission for [IIS_IUSRS] user to Full control
4. Press OK

All done.

Answer (score 0):

I Had tried like give the permissions and change in IIS regarding the identity but I was getting same error.

I just keep the following files underneath the path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" and problem is gone.

1. give the full control permission to recent folder.
2. cvtres.exe (XML configuration File)
3. cvtres (application).

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the options here without any luck.
What worked for me was to simply remove the application pool and recreate it.

No need for extra permissions on any folder.

Answer (score -1):

I have all permissions about writing and reading but I'm starting to get that error.

I can suggest "restart machine" 
At least, it works for me