# Cannot run MVC 3 application from IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I was running my application using visual studio development server and it is http. Now I would like to test my application with https so I have decided to host my application in IIS. In Visual Studio I followed below steps.

1. Select Project properties.
2. Select Web tab.
3. Select 'Use local IIS Web server' radio button
4. Create virtual directory.

And virtual directory created successfully. When I run from IIS it is showing error page with below message.

'CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\PTCApplication\544b56b3\5afd9aa\App_global.asax.gy4m0ojh.dll' -- 'Access is denied. ''

Do I need to set Home Controller,Action method explicitly?
Please provide any reference URL. Step by Step guidance will be more helpful

This link solved my problem. --> [error cs0016 could not write to output file access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974725/error-cs0016-could-not-write-to-output-file-access-is-denied)

Comment: Uncheck readonly property for the file you mentioned.

Comment: @G01 - I have UnChecked readonly property for entire project. Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300389/cs0016-could-not-write-to-output-file-error-when-starting-an-app-in-iis-7 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974725/error-cs0016-could-not-write-to-output-file-access-is-denied. Try using `aspnet_regiis -i` or change `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem`/`NetworkService`.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto - Link which you shared resolved my issue. Thanks.